# SVN - cleaning the project

Tags: svn, netbeans

I am working on a big project. After some updates it totally stopped working on my local machine. Maybe I have failed resolving some conflicts or something but I am not able to fix that anymore.

This is why I want to get the clean files from the server. First thing I thought about was deleting all files and just update the project. But there is something called "cleanup" will that work the same way? I tried to read about it but honestly I dont understand everything clearly

Comment: Well, deleting all the files fixed my problem. I did not try to cleanup

Answer (score 1):

[Cleanup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.cleanup.html) is try to repair your working copy. It is not try to resolve the conflict or such things.

To clear up your code you can delete the checkout and do `svn checkout` again.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a long time since the question was posted, but for some people that end up here through Google or some other search-engine...

You can actually do a "Revert Modifications" with Subversion in Netbeans. The way I do this is by selecting the messed-up folder (or file) in the Projects window, and then press the right-mousebutton. The context menu apears and under "Subversion" you can click on "Revert Modifications".

The pop-up that you'll get enables you to revert that selected folder back to any previous commit.

Hope it helps anyone.